# Are "I have no idea" and "I have no ideas" both correct, and if so, are they synonymous?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, negation, synonyms

I am considering these two sentences:

- I have no idea.
- I have no idea**s**.

Are they both correct, and if so, are they synonymous?

Comment: Franck, interestingly in a situation where yuou would say "I have no idea":  you *definitely would not say* "I have no ideas".  It would sound like "learning English" or "deliberate silly baby talk".

Comment: There's a difference in nuance: *"I have no idea."* = I really don't know. I have not even a single idea, no comprehension whatsoever. *"I have no idea**s**."* = I am all out of ideas. I can't make any suggestions. No original concepts come to mind for me regarding this topic.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

They are both correct and they do not mean the same thing.

"I have no idea" means "I do not know the answer to your particular question." It is about a complete lack of knowledge. It is a counterpart to a less common phrase "I have an idea what the answer is", which is used before answering a question when you think you know what the answer might be, but you are not sure that you are correct.

"I have no ideas" means "I am not creative and I have no original thoughts." It can also have the related meaning, if you are asked to come up with something to do, that "I cannot think of anything to do."

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea.

Comment: Note: "I have no idea" is a very common, borderline idiomatic phrase, which might be said in casual conversation on any given day; whereas "I have no ideas" is not something a person would say very often. The latter would likely be used very situationally as a statement about a specific problem.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt emphasizing what Brian said.  "I have no ideas" **can only exist as an answer to an obscure question such as**: "John, do you have any ideas for the new TV ad we are working on?" Even in that case it would be VERY unusual to answer "I have no ideas". You'd say something like "I've come up with no ideas so far".

Comment: @Fattie I can think of much less obscure questions, such as, WIFE: "Where can we go out to eat tonight that will make everybody happy?" HUSBAND: "I have no ideas."

Comment: @ohwilleke yup. Similar to "drawing a blank".

Comment: My usual use of _"I have no ideas"_ would be in the context of a "brain-storming" meeting, either about something technical or about something that needs immediate attention. "Did you see what Twitter is saying about our new product - gather the managers in the conference room and let's figure out what to do".  Time passes, everyone is in the conference room, and the boss asks everyone, one-by-one, how to respond.  When they get to me: "Sorry, I have no ideas".

Comment: Probably worth a separate question, but what about the opposite form as a question? e.g. "do you have an idea about xxx", would it be the question for "I have no idea" or "I have no ideas"?

Comment: @ohwilleke I'm afraid I feel that would be an extremely unusual reply. It would be beyond not-idiomatic and in to "really unusual"; you'd assume Husband was making a specific joke, or something. (For example, as in FlyDog57 's example, maybe Husband works in advertising and he is parodying that sort of sentence.)  I think the overwhelming point for OP is that the rare phrase "I have no ideas" is **absolutely not** the same as "I have no idea".

Answer (score 4):

To **have no idea** is a phrase or idiom–depending which reference you consult–whose meaning is easily found in most online dictionaries. It has in fact *two* different meanings.

1. *[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/have-no-idea)*

> ### have no idea
>
> phrase
>
> (level) B1 informal ***to not know something***:
>
> - "Where's Serge?" "I've no idea."
> - We had no idea when the power might come back on.
> - "What do you think Bonnie would like for her birthday?" "I have absolutely no idea."

*[Oxford Learners' Dictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/idea)*

> idiom
> **have no idea**, **not have the faintest**, **first**, etc. **idea** (informal)
> used to emphasize that you do not know something
>
> “What's she talking about?” “I have no idea.”
>      *He hasn't the faintest idea how to manage people*.
>      *I had no idea she'd had such a difficult life.*
>      *I don't have any idea where he is.*

## However…

2. *[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/have%20no%20idea)* classifies it as an idiom, and offers two definitions

> 1. to not know or understand
>    *I **have no idea** what you're talking about.*
> 2. —used to reply to someone as an emphatic "yes"
>        "Was it hard?" "*You **have no idea** (how hard it was)!*"

*Longman Dictionary* concurs with the above and completely ignores the version with personal pronoun "I", and adds this detail

> *spoken* used when you are telling someone that something is extremely good, bad etc
>
> - *You **have no idea** how worried I was*.

[*Collins Dictionary's* definition](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/you-have-no-idea-youve-no-idea) implies that it is most commonly used with the second person singular

> **you have no idea/you've no idea** (phrase)
> You can say you *have no idea* to emphasize how good or bad something is.
> [informal, emphasis]
>
> - We are both so happy, **you have no idea**.
> - **You have no idea** how depressed it made me

While the meaning of “I have no idea”, in its uncountable sense, is similar to  [“I don't have a clue”](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/havent-a-clue) and the Victorian-sounding [“I haven't got the foggiest”](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/not-have-the-foggiest-not-have-the-foggiest-idea#:%7E:text=If%20you%20say%20that%20you,you%20do%20not%20know%20something.);  the second phrase **“I have no ideas"**, with the stress on *no*, would suggest the speaker lacked the ability and imagination to create something original.

Comment: I don't think the emphasis idiom can be used in the first person.

Comment: @Barmar Maybe for the second meaning the first person shouldn't be used in the present simple, but if it was in the past simple? "**I had no idea what I was letting myself in for** *when I volunteered with a group of other mums and dads to look after 30 eight-year-olds in summer camp.*“ P.S See the OP's comment which set off alarm bells in my head :)